# What is AO222 based design in concept of design of CMOS cell library?

Tags: digital-logic, design, cmos

I am reading a paper "Static Implementation of QDI Asynchronous Primitives" by P. Maurine, J.B. Rigaud, F. Bouesse, G. Sicard, and M. Renaudin.

They designed a cell library using AO222 gate, What is that exactly? Can anyone point to any document that shed a bit of light on this "AO222" term which I never heard of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AO222 just means And-Or 2 2 2 which logically means: 3 2-input ands feeding into 1 3-input or.

Most inverting complex gates are actually implemented in a single CMOS stage, but non-inverting gates, like the one you mention, need at least two stages.  AO222 is most likely made from a AOI222 and an inverter.

AOI222 = 3 2-input ands feeding into one 3-input or feeding into an inverter.  Implemented usually with a single stage complex CMOS gate.

Other examples are OAI32 (or and invert) or ao21 (the one just converts into skipping the first stage, so a single input goes to the or, the other two inputs go into an and gate, then the or).

Below is a picture with a few logic diagrams to help explain:
[image: a few complex gate examples]

Comment: Ops! I got it. Now all those magic numbers make sense. Is there a reference to all these abbreviations ? I will accept your answer.

Comment: Not as far as I know, because the naming convention becomes pretty explanatory once you get the hang of it.  There is not a 'complete list' because you could technically create an AOI999 or something crazy.  Of course in a single stage, such a complex gate would require a stack of 9 FET's, which is too much to function properly.  But the naming convention CAN define it.